# Need regex expression to make search more lazy

Tags: regex

what regular expression can I use to make search lazy.

**Input data:**

```
SOA/finance/CloudSync_rev6.5 https://abc/xmlpserver/services/ExternalReporService
```

Regex I am using :

```
(\/\w*\/)+?
```

**Output matches are :**

```
 1. /finance/ 
 2. //
 3. /xmlpserver/
```

I just need to find first match i.e `/finance/`. How can I make search more lazy?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert of `nsregularexpression` but what you can do:

- Remove the `global` search, if you do so your regex engine will return after the first match (should be available) [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kbdZe5/2/)
- If not use the following regex `^\/?[^\/]*(\/\w*\/)` or `^[^\/]*(\/\w*\/)` and refer to the first matching group via back reference `\1, $1` [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kbdZe5/1/)
- If available you can also use a positive lookbehind `(?<=^\/?\w+)(\/\w*\/)` or `(?<=^\w+)(\/\w*\/)` to impose additional constraint before matching the beginning of your string [**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/CDacm4/1/)